# AWS Code Deploy (CI) failure - Connection refused error

Tags: amazon-web-services

Our deployments on AWS Code Deployment service started to fail recently with the below error.

```
Error CodeScriptFailed
Script Nameaws/validateService.sh
MessageScript at specified location: aws/validateService.sh failed with exit code 4
Log TailLifecycleEvent - ValidateService
Script - aws/validateService.sh
[stderr]--2018-07-27 20:23:12--  http://localhost:8081/
[stderr]Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
[stderr]Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8081... failed: Connection refused.
```

Our appspec.yml content is as follows:

```
  AfterInstall:
    - location: aws/afterInstall.sh
      timeout: 900
      # runas: catt
  #   - location: 
  #     timeout:
  #     runas:
# During the ApplicationInstall deployment lifecycle event, run the commands 
#   in the script specified in "location".
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: aws/applicationStart.sh
      timeout: 900
      # runas: ec2-user
# During the ValidateService deployment lifecycle event, run the commands 
#   in the script specified in "location".
  ValidateService:
    - location: aws/validateService.sh
      timeout: 90
      # runas: ec2-user
```

Content of the validateService.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60
wget localhost:8081
```

I have increased the sleep time from 10 to 60 seconds and timeout value in appspec.yml from 60 to 90 seconds which hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After increasing the timeout period of the script from 90 seconds to 240 seconds, script completed successfully.

It appears that Node.js application started to take longer to brought up.